# Unable to boot VMs on hyper-v

Tags: hyper-v

I need some advise and assistance regarding the testing of Hyper-V.
Here is my h/ware configuration:

1) Intel i5 processor (i5-750)
2) Intel M/B DP55WB
3) 6 GB DDR3 RAM

OS = Server 2008 R2 Standard (evaluation copy).

I installed 2008 R2 on my machine and added hyper-v role to it. I created 2 VMs and installed OS. But after finishing the OS installation the VMs are not booting up.
After finishing the OS installation, the VM reboots automatically (normal behaviour) and shows "preparing your system for first time" after that it reboots and didn't come online.

Few things to notice, when I am running "securable" on my server 2008 R2 OS it shows that processor is not supporting h/ware virtulization, but (since my desktop is dual boot) when I am running "securable" on my windows 7 OS, it shows that process "does" supports hardware virtulization. VT option is already enabled in BIOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer, and a question:

First the answer:

- 2008 R2 OS with Hyper-V runs in a virtual 0 sesion, so virtualization is NOT available... ANY MORE, as the app runs in a hypervisor already ;) Plus you could not start th eVM even one time without that.

Now the question:

- What OS do you try to install in the VM?